# Will Java(jdk/jre) 64-bit support 32-bit application?

Tags: java, java-8, 32bit-64bit

I've built jdk64-bit from openjdk:https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/ in solaris 10.

```
 Oracle Solaris 10 8/11 s10x_u10wos_17b X86
  Copyright (c) 1983, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
                            Assembled 23 August 2011
```

```
bash-3.2$ isainfo -v
64-bit amd64 applications
        avx xsave pclmulqdq aes sse4.2 sse4.1 ssse3 popcnt tscp cx16 sse3 sse2
        sse fxsr mmx cmov amd_sysc cx8 tsc fpu
32-bit i386 applications
        avx xsave pclmulqdq aes sse4.2 sse4.1 ssse3 popcnt tscp cx16 sse3 sse2
        sse fxsr mmx cmov sep cx8 tsc fpu
```

But my project is 32-bit application. Will java(JRE) 64-bit work with 32-bit application? Will there be any issues? Will it affect performance?

Comment: How exactly is your project "32-bit"? What in your java application is limited/bound to 32-bit?

Comment: For the jar byte code should not matter, it doesn't matter what environment it was created on, be it 32 bit or 64 bit.